# Windows XP doesn't recognize iPhone, can't transfer videos

Tags: windows-xp, iphone, file-transfer

I'm struggling to transfer my videos from my iPhone 4s to my PC.

The PC runs on Windows XP and many tutorial videos just say "Plug it in, when it shows on My Computer, open it and you're done".

Great, except that it doesn't show as an attachment in *My Computer* other than a camera/scanner.

Comment: Although a drastic option, try using another OS? Is a iPhone 4s backwards compatible with Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP requires drivers to be able to recognize the iPhone or iPod when plugged into the USB port. Apple provides these for free but requires you to install iTunes to get them. That is the simplest option.

Alternately, if you don't want iTunes there are more technical ways to install the drivers. Here is a [link](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3741-how-to-install-ipod-and-iphone-driver-without-itunes) to directions how to do so. You will need to install WinRAR and use it to extract files.

Comment: Thanks Charlie, already have itunes installed & I can download my photos & music but not my videos. Hmmm... sounds as though it might be something really simple that I'm missing?